# Proteus gives unrecognized attribute 17 for STM32 Hello World in C

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, c, proteus, gcc

Here is my simple C program for the STM32, I tested it on QEMU, and it flashes the LED successfully, but when I try to load the `main.elf` file into the MCU on Proteus, I get errors.

*main.c*

```c
extern void *_estack;

void Reset_Handler();

void *vectors[] __attribute__((section(".isr_vector"), used)) = {
    &_estack,
    &Reset_Handler
};

int main();

//void __attribute__((naked, noreturn)) Reset_Handler() {
void Reset_Handler() {
    main();
}

typedef unsigned int u32;

void delay(u32 x) {
    while (x) {
        x--;
        int y = 100000;
        while (y) y--;
    }
}

#define mem(a, b) *((u32*)(a + b))

int main() {
    u32 LED = 1 << 12;
    u32 r3 = 0x40021000;
    mem(r3, 24) = mem(r3, 24) | 16;
    r3 = 0x40011000;
    mem(r3, 16) = LED;
    mem(r3, 4) = (mem(r3, 4) & 0xFFF0FFFF) | 0x30000;

    while(1) {
        mem(r3, 20) = LED;
        delay(700);
        mem(r3, 16) = LED;
        delay(300);
    }
}
```

*main.ld*

```
ENTRY(main)
MEMORY
{
  FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 128K
  RAM (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 20K

}

SECTIONS
{
        .text :
        {
                KEEP(*(.isr_vector))
                *(.text)
                *(.text.*)
                *(.rodata)
                _sidata = .;
        } >FLASH

        /* Initialized data will initially be loaded in FLASH at the end of the .text section. */
    .data : AT (_sidata) 
    {
                _sdata = .;
                *(.data)                /* Initialized data */
                _edata = .;
        } >RAM

        .bss : {
                _sbss = .;
                *(.bss)         /* Zero-filled run time allocate data memory */
                _ebss = .;
        } >RAM
    
    _estack = ORIGIN(RAM) + LENGTH(RAM);
 }
```

*Compilation steps:*

```
set -e
CFLAGS="-Wl,-T./main.ld -nostartfiles -fno-common -O0 -g -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb"
arm-none-eabi-gcc $CFLAGS -o main.elf main.c
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -Obinary main.elf main.bin
```

*Error log from Proteus*
[image: Proteus error log]

Comment: What happens if you run `arm-none-eabi-readelf -hls` on main.elf? I wonder if there's something inside the ELF file that Proteus doesn't like.

Comment: I've never used proteus, but assuming main.ld defines the elf file, I suspect there's some invalid data there. Where did you obtain the .ld file?  Usually, this file is configured for you by the development environment depending on the target. You must use the correct linker file for the correct target.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but proteus uses dwarf-2 elf file for debugging, so you need to add one flag to generate that because by default generated file is in dwarf 4, the flag is -gdwarf2 check this link also http://embeddedlaboratory.blogspot.com/2022/11/fatal-simulation-error-while-debugging.html?m=1

Answer (score 2):

You must load ELF file from Release Folder instead Debug Folder. First, click build release icon!